# find command with -regex and -exec, regex help needed

Tags: regex, bash, find

I have a directory with a bunch of person images in it.  Unfortunately the system the images are coming from has its own unique IDs for a bunch of person images that are not used in any other systems at the business (ie guests have a picture but aren't actually in the employee/customer db....just in the picture server's storage).  Fortunately pictures of 8 or more integers followed by an extension are unwanted (I've seen .bmp and .jpg...but there could be others).  I've attempted the following find command as a test before I swap the ls -lh with an rm -f and script the removal of the photos for other systems.  I am guessing I am misunderstanding regular expressions, as that is usually the case, but everywhere I look sure seems like the following should work for what I am looking for.  The \d{8,} does not appear to be working as removing it finds everything just fine, but I don't want everything....just those with 8 or more integers followed by whatever.  What am I overlooking here?

```
find /path/to/dir -regex '\/path\/to\/dir\/\d{8,}.*' -exec ls -lh {} \;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if `find` regex types are system-specific. I've seen in the Linux one that it has several types of regular expressions (POSIX are different from Emacs). It seems that the default regex in find are emacs-like. I've seen that `find` also has a `-regextype` option, so, using the `posix-extended` you can get something similar to what you want:

```
find /path/to/dir -regextype posix-extended -regex '/path/to/dir/[0-9]{8,}.*' -exec ls -lh {} \;
```

but you don't have `\d` on those type of regexes (I think they come from Perl-type regex only), and don't need backslashes for `/`. Anyway, these works.

Comment: Thanks much.  I should find a good book to read by the fireplace about regular expressions during the cold winter.  What better way to feel warmth than reading a book on regular expressions during a time of cold weather.

Comment: Haha, that's true... :) Add to it Perl or Emacs-Lisp, and then would be round perfect :)